# Docker WSL2 SSL certificate for local HTTPS

Tags: docker, nginx, ssl, docker-compose

I'm running Windows 10 Pro and WSL2 (using Ubuntu 20.4) and want to set docker up so that I can dev locally using `https`.

In my windows `/etc/hosts` I have set up the following aliases.

```
127.0.0.1 api.myapp.local
127.0.0.1 client.myapp.local
127.0.0.1 admin.myapp.local

# Added by Docker Desktop
192.168.5.81 host.docker.internal
192.168.5.81 gateway.docker.internal

# To allow the same kube context to work on the host and the container:
127.0.0.1 kubernetes.docker.internal
# End of section
```

I checked my `/etc/hosts` in WSL and verified that the changes had been automatically persisted.

In my `docker-compose` file I have the following two services to A) create certificates B) mount them to my `nginx` container

```
version: "3"

networks:
  myapp:
    driver: bridge

services:
  # Build certificates for nginx.
  mkcert:
    container_name: mkcert
    image: vishnunair/docker-mkcert
    environment: 
      domain: client.myapp.local,admin.myapp.local
    volumes:
      - ./nginx/certs-enabled/:/root/.local/share/mkcert
  nginx:
    volumes:
      - ./nginx/certs-enabled/:/etc/nginx/certs
      - ./nginx/logs:/var/log/nginx
      - ./nginx/sites-enabled:/etc/nginx/conf.d
    container_name: nginx
    depends_on:
      - mkcert
    image: nginx:1.19
    command: nginx -g "daemon off;"
    networks:
      - ${NETWORK}
    ports:
      - 80:80
      - 443:443
```

The certificates that get installed to `./nginx/certs-enabled` are mounted successfully into the container and I installed the generated `rootCA.pem admin.myapp.pem client.myapp.pem` certificates into windows `Trusted Root Certificates`.   a `rootCA-key.pem admin.myapp-key.pem, client.myapp-key.pem` are also generated, but I don't install these as I don't believe that's required?

I restarted my PC and if I visit `https://admin.myapp.local` for example, I get the following error: [image] the thing that confuses me about this is that the certificate that is being used for that local domain is an expired VMWare one, but I'm not using VMWare with docker (it's running through hypervisor as far as I'm aware, and I've also configured/installed the appropriate certs for that domain)

Nginx config for completeness

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    server_name client.myapp.local default_server;
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl;

    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/certs/client.myapp.local.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/certs/client.myapp.local-key.pem;

    server_name client.myapp.local;

    error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;

    include /etc/nginx/snippets/myapp-common.conf;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was extremely frustrating, I uninstalled VMWare from my machine and rebooted, everything now works.   Something must be conflicting when resolving the host

Comment: Were you through with WSL2 with this?